# CSS media query for iPad Pro 12.9 3rd generation

Tags: css, ipad

I'm trying to detect the above device and size web content accordingly.

The below query works for every iPad Pro device apart from 12.9 inch 3rd generation.  Does anyone know the correct parameters for width / height?

```
/* iPad pro */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1024px)
and (max-device-width: 1366px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{
}
```

I have now tried the code below as suggested.  It still does not work on iPad Pro 12.9 3rd generation only. Screenshot of iPad simulator attached.  The login section should fill the width of the screen

```
/* Landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: landscape)
{
    div.information
    {
        width:1290px;
        padding-left:20px;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
}

/* Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: portrait)
{
    div.information
    {
        width:950px;
        padding-left:20px;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing a similar issue with the iPad Pro 12.9 2020 version. Media queries aren't recognised on page load, but strangely when I change the rotation to landscape and change it back it works.

Answer (score 0):

The following query below should work for you. I added an orientation question to the statement to specify which way you're holding the iPad. Also, instead of using 2 width values, you need to replace the max value with a height value instead (which will change depending on if you're holding the device in a landscape or portrait manner.

```
/* Landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: landscape)  {}

/* Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: portrait)  {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but doesn't seem to be working. Please see above